# identificar um clique fora da div com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom eu sei como identificar um clique em Cida de um elemento. Eu faço assim:

```
// Fecha Sidenav
$("#Close_Sidenav").click(function() {
    $("#mySidenav").hide();
});
```

Porém eu preciso que o `$("#mySidenav").hide()`  seja executado quando eu clicar no elemento `Close_Sidenav` e quando eu clicar fora do elemento `mySidenav`.

Como eu faço isso?

Para mais informações estou tentando fazer esse menu fechar quando clico fora dele.
[Menu](https://jsfiddle.net/q35xsopx/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes adicionar um auscultador de evento a `window` ou `document` e no momento do clique verificar se o `event.target` está dentro do menu. Para optimizar um pouco podes ter uma flag do menu, para evitar correr código caso o menu esteja fechado...

Poderia ser algo assim:

```
var menuAberto = false;

// Fecha Sidenav
function fechaSideNav() {
    $("#mySidenav").hide();
    $(".shadow-full").hide();
    menuAberto = false;
}
$("#Close_Sidenav").click(fechaSideNav);

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!menuAberto) return;
    var foraMenu = !$(e.target).closest('#mySidenav')[0];
    if (foraMenu) fechaSideNav();
})

// Abre Sidenav
$("#Open_Sidenav").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#mySidenav").toggle(500);
    menuAberto = true;
    $("body").append('<div class="shadow-full"></div>');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fdm4j2k2/

Comment: Muito obrigado era isso mesmo que eu queria